# Use Ansible inventory IP in Playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file called `inventory.ini` which contains exactly just:

```
10.0.0.4
10.0.0.5
```

I would like to use the IPs listed here in the my Playbook under the variable `ip_address`:

```
- name: Import & load configuration file into PAN-OS
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    ip_address: "{{ SOMETHING-GOES-HERE }}"
    username: "#{PALOS_USERNAME}#"
    password: "#{PALOS_PASSWORD}#"
    config_file: ""
    load_file: ""

  roles:
  - role: PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks

  tasks:
  - name: wait for reboot
    panos_check:
      ip_address: "{{ ip_address }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
      interval: 5
      timeout: 900

  - name: import configuration file into PAN-OS
    panos_import:
      ip_address: "{{ ip_address }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
      file: "{{ config_file }}"
      category: "configuration"
```

I have tried using `{{ inventory_hostname }}`, but that brings back `localhost` instead. I have also tried using `{{ ansible_host }}`, but that brings back `127.0.0.1`

Does anyone know how I can use the IPs listed in the inventory in place of the variable as it loops through each deployment?

Just to note, I run the playbook as such:

```
ansible-playbook panos-config.yml -i inventory.ini --extra-vars "config_file=./xml-config/asdf.xml load_file=asdf.xml" -vvv
```

Ansible version is 2.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change the `hosts` to `all`, and leave `{{ ansible_host }}` in the `ip_address` variable field. The IPs get pulled from the inventory file and deploys fine. Like so:

```
- name: Import & load configuration file into PAN-OS
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    ip_address: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    username: "#{PALOS_USERNAME}#"
    password: "#{PALOS_PASSWORD}#"
    config_file: ""
    load_file: ""

  roles:
  - role: PaloAltoNetworks.paloaltonetworks

  tasks:
  - name: wait for reboot
    panos_check:
      ip_address: "{{ ip_address }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
      interval: 5
      timeout: 900

  - name: import configuration file into PAN-OS
    panos_import:
      ip_address: "{{ ip_address }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
      file: "{{ config_file }}"
      category: "configuration"
```